# Setup remote GIT repository via SSH? (No code access to the remote location)

Tags: git, ssh

I have a remote location I want to use as GIT repository. I have SSH access to that location and can copy files there. I can't install or run the GIT executables on the remote location. Can I (and how) use it as the GIT repository for my team?

Comment: How can you have SSH access without the possibility to install Git? Just copy some binaries over to your remote homedir.

Comment: Ask the admin to install git.

Comment: Very funny: I don't have admin rights and the admin won't entertain such requests (don't ask). If I could ask the admin or install by myself l would not have asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is impossible to implement. A Git repository requires a server-side Git suite.

On the other hand, if it's possible to provide an `NFS` or `CIFS` share, you could keep a Git repository on such a share — it would be acted upon by your local Git instance.  Not that I like this approach though...

Comment: Hhm I thought if there is no remote git it still would work via ssh, simply the triggers wouldn't run

Comment: @stwissel, no, when you do any Git exchange "over `SSH`", `SSH` is only there to a) set up its tunnel and b) spawn a special Git process on the server side (the one told by the client); then the remote Git process and the local one exchange their data via the tunnel.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem. I found a palliative solution:

- Use [SSHFS](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) and [Fuse](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) to mount the remote location through ssh as a network drive;
- The people having direct read/write access (me) clone the git repository with its local path;
- Other people clone the repo with an http access.

It's not very efficient but it works.